# How can I get the firebase authentication login working with webflow?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, webflow

I'm trying to connect firebase authentication service with my Webflow website. So far I was able to successfully integrate the "signup" functionality. The user information is successfully transmitted from Webflow to firebase. But when trying to login to an existing account it doesn't seem to be working.

In the following corresponding HTML Element IDs will be in brackets.
On the Webflow login and signup page I'm using **form-input-fields** for the email (`signup-email` / `signin-email`) and password (`signup-password` / `signin-password`). For the submission of the user information I'm using a **link block**.

I'm using the following code in the main footer of the entire Webflow site:

```html
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
  authDomain: "asdfasdf.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "dasdfasdf-2c295",
  storageBucket: "asdfasdfasdf-fasdfasdf.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "asdfasdfasdf",
  appId: "1:1fasdfasdf3:web:e8bdefasdfasdf",
  measurementId: "G-P07ZEPQKMS"
};
  
    // Initialize Firebase and declare "global" variables. all variables declared in this section are accessible to functions that follow.
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const authentication = getAuth(app);
    
   //identify auth action forms
    let signUpForm = document.getElementById('wf-form-signup-form')
    let signInForm = document.getElementById('wf-form-signin-form')

    let signUpButton = document.getElementById('signup-button');
    let signInButton = document.getElementById('signin-button');
    let signOutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

    if (signInButton) {
      console.log("found buttone")
    } else {
      console.log("didn't find button")
    }
   
    //assign event listeners, if the elements exist
    if(typeof(signUpButton) !== null) {
      signUpButton.addEventListener('click', handleSignUp, true)
      } else {console.log("button not found")};
      
     if(typeof(signInButton) !== null) {
      console.log("in sigsnInButton !== null")
      signInButton.addEventListener('click', handleSignIn, true)
      console.log("triggered EventListener")
      } else {console.log("button not found")};
      
      if(typeof signOutButton !== null) {
        signOutButton.addEventListener('click', handleSignOut);
           } else {console.log("button not found")}
    
    //handle signUp
    function handleSignUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        
      const email = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
      const password = document.getElementById('signup-password').value;
      
      console.log("email is " + email);
      console.log("password is " + password + ". Now sending to firebase.");
      
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentication, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
         // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('user successfully created: ' + user.email)
        //////////////////////////////////////// 
        document.getElementById("wf-form-signup").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-fail")[0].style.display = "none"
        document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-done")[0].style.display = "block"
        //////////////////////////////////////// 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      var errorText = document.getElementById('signup-error-message');
      console.log(errorMessage);
      errorText.innerHTML = errorMessage;
      // ..
      //////////////////////////////////////// 
      document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-fail")[0].style.display = "block"
      //////////////////////////////////////// 

    });
    };


      //handle signIn
    function handleSignIn(e) {
        console.log("login started")
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        
      const email = document.getElementById('signin-email').value;
      const password = document.getElementById('signin-password').value;

      console.log("got login info") 

      signInWithEmailAndPassword(authentication, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log('user logged in: ' + user.email);
      // ...
      //////////////////////////////////////// 
      document.getElementById("wf-form-signin").style.display = "none"
      document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-fail")[0].style.display = "none"
      document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-done")[0].style.display = "block"
      //////////////////////////////////////// 
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      var errorText = document.getElementById('signin-error-message');
      console.log(errorMessage);
      errorText.innerHTML = errorMessage;
      //////////////////////////////////////// 
      document.getElementsByClassName("w-form-fail")[0].style.display = "block"
      //////////////////////////////////////// 
    });
    }
    
  function handleSignOut() {
      signOut(authentication).then(() => {
    console.log('user signed out')
    // Sign-out successful.
  }).catch((error) => {
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(errorMessage);
    // An error happened.
  });
  }
  
  onAuthStateChanged(authentication, (user) => {
      let publicElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-onlogin='hide']");
      let privateElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-onlogin='show']");
  
      if (user) {
      // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties         
      
      const uid = user.uid;
      
      privateElements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = "initial";
      });
      
      publicElements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = "none";
      });
      
      console.log(`The current user's UID is equal to ${uid}`);
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out
      publicElements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = "initial";
      });
      
      privateElements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = "none";
      });
      // ...
    }
  });
  </script>
```

here you see the settings of the login **link block**:
[image: here you see the settings of the login link block]
[image]